# iOS Animating two views, stacked on top of each other

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiview

I have problems with animating two views!

I have Two Buttons that are going to slide up different Views from bottom.

And the thing I want to do is:

[image: screenshot]

I'm animating `RegisterView` like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var registerViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var registerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var registerViewBottomContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.registerViewBottomContraint.constant = -registerViewHeight.constant

    }

@IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.registerViewBottomContraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }
```

First: How do I correctly add stack-upped views on top of each other?
Second: Is there a way to do the transform easily from a button to a view?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You could animate the views like this [Objective-C]:

```
CGRect viewFrame = self.registerView.frame;
self.registerView.frame = CGRectMake(viewFrame.origin.x, viewFrame.origin.y + viewFrame.size.height, viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height);
self.registerView.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self. registerView.frame = viewFrame;
                     self. registerView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```